# How can I remove a subclass of SKSpriteNode from parent correctly in Swift (to be removed from array, space on screen...)?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I've created a subclass:

`class EnemySprite: SKSpriteNode`

and added an enemy in my game scene using this code:

```
let enemy = EnemySprite(imageNamed:"enemy.png")
self.addChild(enemy)
```

Now when I shoot on the enemy I have the code:

```
enemy.removeFromParent()
```

The enemy is not seen on the screen, but the `_enemiesSpritesArray.count` remains the same. Also, when I shoot to the area where the enemy was, bullets stop there as if the sprite is still in the same spot.
I've tried to add:

```
override func removeFromParent() {
    super.removeFromParent()
}
```

but still the same.

How can I remove the sprite completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the instance from the array as well.

```
if let index = enemiesSpritesArray.index(of: enemy) {
    enemiesSpritesArray.remove(at: index)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friend! it works not great :) and to think in the era of auto count no need to release but still need to remove manually items from array...

Comment: Removing it from your array has nothing to do with ARC and auto-release. The fact that it is in the array means the object still exists which is why the collision detection might be a bit funny.

Comment: Before I started swift I worked with Cocos-2d, there removing a child remove it automatically from arrays. I guess I became a little spoiled... ;)